# Avoid infinity in division in signals in Matlab Simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink

When dividing two sinusoidal signals in matlab simulink, It can result in an infinite or large output. This may be avoided using saturation tool box but it seems to be an inefficient method. Is there a way out of this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can add a small constant to the denominator.

Comment: Smart answer when considering the mathematical view. The above problem will not be an issue in practical implementation of the concept. But i want to match my simulations very close to real time behaviour. :)

Comment: can you tweak the sampling frequency and phase to avoid sampling near zero?

Comment: Yes. But it will result in loss of information as well. System is such that, division should happen at any given condition of the two sinusoidal signals(Phase,frequency etc) + Any loss of information or adjustments to division can violate the simulation outcomes.

Comment: May I ask what you are doing here? To me it seems that getting this kind of output must be the result of doing something wrong. For all I know, an infinite output from a correctly executed simulation would mean the this would happen in real time as well. This would be an unstable state and will cause system overload. In other words it should be avoided to all cost.

Comment: @Shai Smart answer to twerk the sampling frequency to avoid sampling at zero. Similar things is actually done in reality. For example the modulation with a raised cosine in telecommunication to maxmize the gain at the sampling points.

Answer (score 3):

The signal in the denominator can be set to non-zero by adding a small number to it before the division. This number can for example be obtained by using the `eps` function.